# istream / ostream parameters with arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, istream

Ok, so I have this code where I'm manipulating arrays, but I know I'm doing something pretty wrong here and I cant identify it. I'm supposed to use istream and ostream parameters... I think, along with arrays and int variables. Here's the code and what I'm getting:

```
#include <iostream>;

#include <fstream>;

using namespace std;


//input data
void inputData(istream &, int[], int);

//print data
void printData(ostream &, const int[], int);

//copy one array to another
void copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int);

// copy one array to another in reverse
void revCopy(const int orig[], int rev[], int);

int main()
{
ifstream in;
ofstream out;

int x[10];
int y[10];
int z[10];

inputData( cin, x, 10);

printData(cout, x, 10);

copyArray(x, y, 10);

printData(cout, y, 10);

revCopy (y, z, 10);

printData(cout, z, 10);




return 0;
}

//input data
void inputData(istream & cin, int x[], int i)
{
cout << "Enter in 10 Values for array \"x\"" << endl;


for(i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    cin >> x[i];
}
}

//print data
void printData(ostream & cout, const int x[], int i)
{
for (i = 0; i <10; i++)
{
    cout << x[i];
}

}

//copy one array to another
void copyArray(const int orig[], int dup[], int)
{

}


// copy one array to another in reverse
void revCopy(const int orig[], int rev[], int)
{

}
```

Here's what im getting so far, I was trying to test the print function before moving on and I can't seem to get past this:

```
Enter in 10 Values for array "x"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12345678910-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-85899346
0-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-85899346
0-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460-858993460Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm new to c++ and am in a class now, but this one has got me stumped, been trying to figure it out for the past couple of days and my instructor has been unavailable. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Please explain what you expect that code to do in addition to what output you get... While updating the post consider removing "new here"/"thank you" as they don't provide any additional details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You declare

```
int z[10];
```

At this point all the data inside `z` is uninitialized and any accesses to it are undefined behavior. Later your code calls

```
revCopy (y, z, 10);
```

But this function is not implemented yet; nothing gets put into `z` at all and it remains uninitialized data. So a call to

```
printData(cout, z, 10);
```

Will cause undefined behavior, hence the junk output you see. I suggest you zero initialize `z` first if you are just testing before you implement your other functions.